# ExpressJS Swagger UI Display Request Duration

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-ui

https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/

I want to output the request duration and based on the available configurations, the `displayRequestDuration` is by default false so on my express app, I have added it in the options object but it does not seem to be working

[Swagger Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgoVk.png)

Is there any examples of how to correctly configure this parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is only for the use of `swagger-jsdoc` and `swagger-ui-express` packages.

The `displayRequestDuration` can be defined in the `swaggerUI.setup()` function. For example

app.use("/swagger", swaggerUI.serve, swaggerUI.setup(swaggerDocs, {
swaggerOptions:{
displayRequestDuration: true
}
}));